# JAVA: Filter particular column in csv using stream api

Tags: java

I have read CSV file from ftp server which as cell values in the format of

```
"Col 1","Col 2","Col 3",”Col 4”,”Col 5”,”Col 6”,……”Col 80” 
"","","Yes",”A,B,C”,"12345","0",….. “XYZ 20190523 10:46:00 PM” 
"","","Yes",”D,E,F”,"12345","1",….. “XYZ 20190523 10:46:00 PM” 
"","","Yes",”X,Y”,"6789","0",….. “XYZ 20190523 10:46:00 PM”
```

Need to apply split, filtering Col 6 and print the data ignoring record for 0 in col 6

I have tried the below:

```
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
       InputStreamReader(stream));
       String line = null;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       String[] arr = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
          for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
              if(arr[i].equals("\"Col 6\"")) {
                  index=i;                         
                }
              System.out.println("CSV Data is :"+ arr[i]+"");
           }                
       }
   }
```

Need to use either of following:
- map
- hashmap
- filter (lambda functions)-- which will apply cndition like Col 6 >0 and print data accordingly
- getter and setter (if any)

And other methods or sample code please sugggest

Comment: Can you please post the code you tried?

Comment: I have posted piece of it above

Comment: `Need to use either of following: - map - hashmap - filter (lambda functions)` Why? 1st line contains header, parse it separately. Once you know the desire column index, you can easy parse the data part.

Comment: To read CSV data, **use a CSV Parser**. Don't try to use `split()`, because it doesn't handle the CSV escaping rules.

Comment: On a side note, I sure hope that your CSV data is only using regular `"` quotes, not those funky `“` and `”` quotes.

Comment: But if won't use split then how the data will get printed when there is other characters between double quotes say "A, B, C, 20190523 11:52:00".

Answer (score 0):

But need to fix CSV:

```
"Col 1","Col 2","Col 3","Col 4","Col 5","Col 6","Col 80"
"","","Yes","A,B,C","12345","0","XYZ 20190523 10:46:00 PM"
"","","Yes","D,E,F","12345","1","XYZ 20190523 10:46:00 PM"
"","","Yes","X,Y","6789","0","XYZ 20190523 10:46:00 PM"
```

Example below:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class SampleCSVParser {
    public List<Map<String, String>> parse(Path csvPath) throws IOException {
        Reader in = new FileReader(csvPath.toFile());

        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                .withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)
                .withDelimiter(',')
                .withTrim()
                .parse(in);


        return StreamSupport
                        .stream(records.spliterator(), false)
                        .filter(csvRecord -> Integer.parseInt(csvRecord.get("Col 6"))>0)
                        .map(csvRecord -> csvRecord.toMap().entrySet().stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                        e -> e.getKey(),
                                        e -> e.getValue()
                                )))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create Interface for CSVFormat?

Comment: org.apache.commons commons-csv 1.6 The project https://github.com/sbzDev/stackoverflow/tree/master/question56280244